# Object key 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, object, axios

I'm getting an object coming from an API and I'm creating new objects inside it with other API responses, ex:

API Response 1: `Obj: {a: 1, b: 2}`

API Response 2: `3`

Creating an object: `Obj.c = 3`

Final result: Obj: `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`

### Problem:

```
console.log(Obj) return Obj: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

console.log(Obj.c) return undefined
```

I am not getting when trying to give a `console.log` after the `.map` in the properties, I can not access the created properties, returns `undefined`. However, when I give a `console.log` on any object, the created properties are there.

### My Code:

```
async getGeneralInfo(token, seed) {
    try {
        API_HEADER.headers.Authorization = token;
        let responseAvaliableCoins = await axios.get(
            BASE_URL + "/coin",
            API_HEADER
        );

        let avaliableCoins = responseAvaliableCoins.data.data.coins;

        avaliableCoins.map(async (coin, index) => {
            if (coin.status === "active") {
                let responseCreateAddress = await axios.post(
                    BASE_URL + "/coin/" + coin.abbreviation + "/address",
                    { seed },
                    API_HEADER
                );

                avaliableCoins[index].address =
                    responseCreateAddress.data.data.address;

                let responseBalance = await axios.get(
                    BASE_URL +
                    "/coin/" +
                    coin.abbreviation +
                    "/balance/" +
                    coin.address,
                    API_HEADER
                );

                avaliableCoins.token = responseBalance.headers[HEADER_RESPONSE];
                avaliableCoins[index].balance = responseBalance.data.data;
            } else {
                avaliableCoins[index].address = undefined;
                avaliableCoins[index].balance = undefined;
            }
        });

        console.warn(avaliableCoins[0].balance); //undefined
        console.warn(avaliableCoins[0]["balance"]); //undefined
        console.warn(avaliableCoins[0].address); //undefined
        console.warn(avaliableCoins[0]["address"]); //undefined

        console.warn("avaliableCoins", avaliableCoins); //All objects are here
        console.warn("avaliableCoins[0]", avaliableCoins[0]); //All objects are here

        return avaliableCoins;
    } catch (error) {
        internalServerError();
        return;
    }
}
```

update -----
[image]

Comment: Did you check to ensure that the 0 index has something. I might just dump the entire availableCoins array to see what you're working with. console.log(avaliableCoins)

Comment: My theory is that you're using Google Chrome, which shows a "live" view when you log objects. Your code isn't `await`ing the result of all the promises returned from the `.map`.

Comment: `const coinUpdates = availableCoins.map( ... etc ... ); await Promise.all(coinUpdates);`

Comment: That `i` next to the object says it was evaluated just now. So possibly its not the same value at the time you wrote to the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function used in `map` is asynchronous.

Right now `map` is being called on all of the coins and before all the asynchronous data can come back the code has already moved on to the `console.warn()` calls.

`availableCoins` will eventually be updated with all the asynchronous data as it is returned, but there is a race condition here since the code is not explicitly waiting for that to happen.

Here is the recommended approach:

- return a modified item from each `async` call in `map`, this will return a `Promise` that will resolve to the modified item when the `async` function completes.
- use `Promise.all()` to wait on the array of `Promises`
- return the resulting array

Here is a simplified version that demonostrates the approach:

```
const getData = () => {
  return Promise.resolve('data');
}

export const getGeneralInfo = async () => {
  let avaliableCoins = [
    { a: 1 },
    { a: 2 }
  ]

  const promises = avaliableCoins.map(async (coin) => {
    let response = await getData();
    // modify coin and return it
    coin.data = response;
    return coin;
  });

  const updatedCoins = await Promise.all(promises);

  console.log(updatedCoins); // [{a: 1, data: 'data'}, {a: 2, data: 'data'}]

  return updatedCoins;
}
```

Your modified function would look like this:

```
async getGeneralInfo(token, seed) {
  try {
    API_HEADER.headers.Authorization = token;
    let responseAvaliableCoins = await axios.get(
      BASE_URL + "/coin",
      API_HEADER
    );

    let avaliableCoins = responseAvaliableCoins.data.data.coins;

    const promises = avaliableCoins.map(async (coin) => {
      if (coin.status === "active") {
        let responseCreateAddress = await axios.post(
          BASE_URL + "/coin/" + coin.abbreviation + "/address",
          { seed },
          API_HEADER
        );

        coin.address =
          responseCreateAddress.data.data.address;

        let responseBalance = await axios.get(
          BASE_URL +
          "/coin/" +
          coin.abbreviation +
          "/balance/" +
          coin.address,
          API_HEADER
        );

        coin.token = responseBalance.headers[HEADER_RESPONSE];
        coin.balance = responseBalance.data.data;
      } else {
        coin.address = undefined;
        coin.balance = undefined;
      }
      return coin;
    });

    availableCoins = await Promise.all(promises);

    console.warn(avaliableCoins[0].balance); //undefined
    console.warn(avaliableCoins[0]["balance"]); //undefined
    console.warn(avaliableCoins[0].address); //undefined
    console.warn(avaliableCoins[0]["address"]); //undefined

    console.warn("avaliableCoins", avaliableCoins); //All objects are here
    console.warn("avaliableCoins[0]", avaliableCoins[0]); //All objects are here

    return avaliableCoins;
  } catch (error) {
    internalServerError();
    return;
  }
}
```